# Access array data with index in Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble accessing a data from an array using the index.

I've the following code in my template.

```html
<a href="#" class="...">{{ fixture.flatOdds.data[0].market_id }}</a>
```

And that throws:

```
TypeError: fixture.flatOdds.data[0] is undefined
```

But fixture.flatOdds.data[0] is defined. When I print out the fixture.flatOdds.data[0] like this:

```
<a href="#" class="...">{{ fixture.flatOdds.data[0] }}</a>
```

It prints out the object just fine. The response,

```
{ "bookmaker_id": 2, "bookmaker_event_id": null, "market_id": 1, "odds": [ { "label": "1", "value": 3, "winning": null, "handicap": null, "total": null, "last_update": { "date": "2018-07-29 08:15:53.000000", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "UTC" } }, { "label": "X", "value": 3.2, "winning": null, "handicap": null, "total": null, "last_update": { "date": "2018-07-29 08:15:53.000000", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "UTC" } }, { "label": "2", "value": 2.38, "winning": null, "handicap": null, "total": null, "last_update": { "date": "2018-07-29 08:15:53.000000", "timezone_type": 3, "timezone": "UTC" } } ] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using axios to load the data from an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that the value is `undefined` at some point in the components lifecycle (you're probably loading it asynchronously). You are going to need be be defensive in the way that you reference your property.

You could use a computed property

```
const component = {
  computed: {
    marketId () {
      if (this.fixture && this.fixture.flatOdds && this.fixture.flatOdds.data) {
        return fixture.flatOdds.data[0].market_id
      }
      return 'unknown'
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could also use a filter,

```
<template>
  <span>{{fixture | getMarketId}}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  filter: {
    getMarketId (obj) {
      if (obj && obj.flatOdds && obj.flatOdds.data) {
        return obj.flatOdds.data[0].market_id
      }
      return 'unknown'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or as per @ittus's example use a `v-if`, but just be careful of which part of your object is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading data asynchronously?
`fixture.flatOdds.data[0]` might not be available when data is not loaded.

You can add `v-if` to check if data is available.

```
   <a href="#" class="..." 
     v-if="fixture.flatOdds.data[0]">
     {{ fixture.flatOdds.data[0].market_id }}
   </a>
```